# QTP - Identifying WebGrid using Div Tag

Tags: html, html-table, qtp, webgrid

I have the following html tag for a Web Grid. How do I use it to identify this Webgrid using the unique Div ID in QTP. I need to use this div id as it's the only unique identifier.

```
<div id="UniqueID"class="rowdetail" width="100%">
<table class="datagrid" width="100%">
<tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">TableName</th></tr>
<tr><td width="25%"> ....</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

I have retrieved Unique ID already using getattribute. I need to use this in my descriptive programming to identify uniquely.

```
Browse(B).Page(P).WbfGrid/WebTable?(?)
```

Let me know if you need more details. I did search the internet but with no help so created a question to serve the purpose.
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your question now.
You cannot identify the **UniqueID** `div` as a `WebTable` since it's a `WebElement` in QTP not a table, however you can use the `div` in order to uniquely identify the `table` since it's the only child object of the `div`. Something like this should work:

```
 Browser("B").Page("P").WebElement("html id:=UniqueID").WebTable("html tag:=TABLE").RowCount()
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being very descriptive in my opening post but would I be able to identify it as webtable or a web grid so I can iterate to get values of each rows and columns